# How to convert a json into HL7 using Mirth Connect 3.4.1?

Tags: javascript, json, mirth, hl7-v3

I define a javascript transformer now, but always tip failure when transformation, the code is as follows:

```
var input = JSON.parse(connectorMessage.getRawData());
var patienId = input.PATIENT_ID;
var patientName = input.PATIENT_NAME;
var idCard = input.ID_NO;
var i = 1;
createSegment("MSH", msg, i++);
msg['MSH']['MSH.1']['MSH.1.1'] = '|';
msg['MSH']['MSH.2']['MSH.2.1'] = '^~\\&';
msg['MSH']['MSH.3']['MSH.3.1'] = patienId;
msg['MSH']['MSH.4']['MSH.4.2'] = patientName;
msg['MSH']['MSH.5']['MSH.5.1'] = idCard;
```

and Exceptions are as follows:

```
Transformer error
ERROR MESSAGE: Error evaluating transformer
com.mirth.connect.server.MirthJavascriptTransformerException: 
CHANNEL:    WsToHttpTest
CONNECTOR:  sourceConnector
SCRIPT SOURCE:  TRANSFORMER
LINE NUMBER:    31
 DETAILS:   TypeError: Cannot set property "1" of undefined to ""
    at f4645dbe-9637-415e-ae39-f3dce72d6eaa:31 (createSegment)
    at f4645dbe-9637-415e-ae39-f3dce72d6eaa:53 (doTransform)
    at f4645dbe-9637-415e-ae39-f3dce72d6eaa:80 (doScript)
    at f4645dbe-9637-415e-ae39-f3dce72d6eaa:82
    at                       com.mirth.connect.server.transformers.JavaScriptFilterTransformer$FilterTransformerTask.doCall(JavaScriptFilterTransformer.java:154)
at com.mirth.connect.server.transformers.JavaScriptFilterTransformer$FilterTransformerTask.doCall(JavaScriptFilterTransformer.java:119)
at com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptTask.call(JavaScriptTask.java:113)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem in your above code starts with `createSegment` code. Until then it works fine.

In your outbound transformer create a dummy message template as follows: 
This is just a namesake template, that you're defining to create a HL7 segment scope.

```
MSH|^~\&|||||||||||
PID||||||||||||||||||||
PD1|||||
```

Considering you receive JSON something like this:

```
{
    "PATIENT_ID": "XXXX",
    "PATIENT_NAME": "John",
    "ID_NO": "454141541"
}
```

I dont think this syntax is correct `createSegment('MSH', msg, i++);`
I have modified the code you provided above:

```
var input = JSON.parse(connectorMessage.getRawData());
var patienId = input.PATIENT_ID;
var patientName = input.PATIENT_NAME;
var idCard = input.ID_NO;
msg=tmp;
createSegment('MSH', msg);
msg['MSH']['MSH.1']= "|";
msg['MSH']['MSH.2']= "^~\\&";
msg['MSH']['MSH.3']= patienId;
msg['MSH']['MSH.4']= patientName;
msg['MSH']['MSH.5']= idCard;
```

You can also increment counter in the HL7 message in your suggested way no wrong. refer counter : [Adding Multiple NTE segments to HL7 message with Mirth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703112/adding-multiple-nte-segments-to-hl7-message-with-mirth)

[image]

Comment: what is in tmp ?

Comment: @brijexecon tmp is the mirth message object for outbound message. msg if for the inbound message